# compile in visual studio with C rules not c++

Tags: c, visual-c++

I want to compile c files using Visual C++.
these files contains c code which generate an error with Visual Studio compiler:

e.g. implicit cast.

```
void* method1();
char * var = method1();
```

This is right in C but not in C++.

is there a way to apply C standard in my project to compile theses files in Visual c++ ?

Comment: There's a guide on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384838.aspx

Comment: Does your source file have a `.c` extension?

Comment: Did you name the files as `.c` and not `.cpp`? Also, the C compiler with Visual C++ is going to be following pretty old standards.

Comment: Have you tried putting your code in an `extern "C"` block ?

Comment: yes, the files have '.c' extension. there is a lot of souruce code, I don't want to modify them all that's why I asked if there is a way to compile the projet wi c standard.

Comment: Yes, you can force CPP files to be compiled as C using `/TC` command line option (it's available in options too in _C/C++_ section item _Advanced_, _Compile As_).

Comment: Did you read the link in @SBI's comment? *By default, the Visual C++ compiler treats all files that end in .c as C source code*. So either you have done something odd, or the "standard" supported by Microsoft (1990?) is *different* than the standard coded to in the C source you have.

Comment: yes, the link is helpfull.

Comment: As another thing, I would suggest posting the *exact* error message, along with a minimal example that shows this error. Is this C++ code including C headers? Or is everything C in your project?

Comment: You should also know that the /Za flag (C/C++->Language) disables Microsoft's language extensions to ANSI C. This can be good if you worry about compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are considering mixing C++ and C code. If you are doing this you may want to use:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
   extern "C" {
#endif

/* all C code here */

#ifdef __cplusplus
   }
#endif
```